# blackberry - need to receive sms within my application without notifying inbox (silently)

Tags: blackberry, sms, filtering

I'm developing a blackberry SMS appication.
Which needs to filter all incoming messages which have only with a specific keyword (ex - Starts with ABC).
The messages with this keywords will not allow goto the inbox.

Is it possible with messageListner ?

I got to know that this may be possible by invoke class. But i don't have a clear idea on this. Could anyboday help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. RIM doesn't provide such function.
But there is another way to achieve this: turn on firewall in the system's option and filter all the sms, now system can't recieve notifications of sms while your application can. This is used in most sms firewall apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jacul. But in firewall the messages from specfic contact or address only can be controlled isn't it ? But i need to filter by key word from sms payload.

Comment: No, as far as I know it is impossible.